# Выбор типа связи и реализации функции "добавление в друзья" с подтверждением

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, crud, связи

Пишу тестовый Facebook, нужен совет в реализации добавления в друзья с подтверждением. Нужен совет в том, какие таблицы нужны и какие связи реализовать, что-бы просто и легко было устанавливать "дружбу", подтверждать её и расторгать.
 Как сейчас я реализовал(как по мне он криво как-то а как сделать правильно не знаю): три таблицы (`users`, `friendships`, `confirm_friendships`) и связи между ними.

```
1. users
:id
:email
 (has_many :friendships, foreign_key: 'requester_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :requesters, through: :friendships, source: :requester
  has_many :responders, through: :friendships, source: :responder)
2. friendships
:id
:requester_id
:responder_id
 (belongs_to :requester, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :responder, class_name: "User"
  has_one   :confirm_friendship)
3. confirm_friendships
:friendship_id
:confirm
 (belongs_to :friendship)
```

Что-бы установить "дружбу" с подтверждением между пользователями я делаю так:

```
u1 = User.first
u2 = User.second
u1.friendships.create!(responder_id: other_user.id)
fr = Friendship.find_by(requester_id: u1.id, responder_id: u2.id)
conf = ConfirmFriendship.create(friendship_id: fr.id, confirm: true)
```

Нужна советы что-бы красиво лаконично и правильно это реализовать.

Comment: достаточно одной таблицы friendships, в которой source_id это id пользовтаеля запросившего/подтвердившего дружбу, а target_id к кому пошёл запрос/подтверждение

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать на манер ВК: когда некое отношение в одну сторону это "подписка на человека", а в обе "дружба". То есть, два человека А и Б считаются друзьями, если в таблице `friendships` есть записи `А -> Б` и `Б -> А`.

К сожалению, в Rails для поиска таких "взаимных друзей" потребуется `JOIN` (соединение) таблицы `friendships` **к самой себе** или выборка записей через `OR`, с которым стало можно работать без SQL только в Rails 5, который ещё не выпущен. На ассоциации, скорее всего, это ляжет плохо, если ляжет вообще.

Чтобы сделать самосоединение (self-join), с одной из сторон таблица должна быть с **алиасом** (псевдонимом), что на языке запросов ActiveRecord выразить малореально (а на Arel будет настолько убойный код, что лучше уж SQL), проще написать на SQL. Но писать SQL в моделях очень не хочется, верно?

...можно сделать [**представление** в БД](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createview.html). Это, кстати, достаточно весёлая область использования ActiveRecord и я практически не встречал её на практике (люди её боятся что ли?), но работает она довольно просто из-за того, что представление в запросах работает очень похоже на **таблицу**. Поэтому можно "притвориться, что создаёшь модель и её таблицу", а **в миграции** на чистом SQL сделать нечто совсем другое:

```sql
CREATE VIEW mutual_friendships AS
  SELECT friendships.*
    FROM friendships
    INNER JOIN friendships AS inv_f -- псевдоним
      ON friendships.target_id = inv_f.source_id
     AND friendships.source_id = inv_f.target_id

-- ...а обратное действие:
DROP VIEW mutual_friendships
```

Это возьмёт те строки таблицы `friendships`, к которым существуют обратные. Для ActiveRecord это будет выглядеть, как таблица `mutual_friendships`, что можно завернуть в модель `MutualFriendship`, делать ассоциации и прочее.

А изменения в `friendships` будут сразу проявляться в представлении, поскольку, по сути, представление это "запрос в обёртке с подписью", запрос будет выполняться каждый раз, когда представление используется.